# PHP + MySQL - how to POST 2 values in single form

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm trying to build a very basic inventory management website for my own personal use. I'm having an issue when trying to build 'Delete' functionality into my list of returned items.

This is the PHP script from the visible webpage:

```
<form action='actions.php' method='post'>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check Connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM computers WHERE status='Available'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='unassigned'>
            <tr>
                <th onclick='sortTable(0)'>Manufacturer</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(1)'>Model</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(2)'>Serial Number</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(3)'>CPU</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(4)'>Memory</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(5)'>HDD</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(6)'>Status</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(7)'>Assignee</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(8)'>Date Assigned</th>
                <th onclick='sortTable(9)'>Date Returned</th>
                <th>ID - TESTING ONLY</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>";
    //output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { $id = $row["sn"];

    {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["manufacturer"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["model"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["sn"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["CPU"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["memory"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["hdd"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["status"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["assignee"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["dateout"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["datein"]."</td>
                <td>" . " <input type='hidden' name = 'id' value= " . $row["sn"] . "> " . "</td>
                <td>" . " <input type='submit' name = 'delete' . ' value='Delete' >" . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }

    }   

    echo "</table>";
    }

    else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
?>
</form>
```

And this is the 'actions.php' file:

```
<?php
$delete = $_POST["delete"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check Connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo "ID is set and it is" . $id;
    }
else {
    echo "Where is the ID you numpty";
    }

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM computers WHERE sn= $id";  
    echo "Deleting Stuff";
    //if ($conn->query($sql === TRUE) {
        //echo "Record deleted successfully";
        //}
   //else {
        //echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
        //}

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

(Please ignore the various testing things I have put in)

The issue I am having of course is that I have defined:

```
name = "id"
```

On each row of my table, so when I press any of the delete buttons on the webpage, the ID that is returned on the actions.php page is the very last $row['sn'], whatever that might be...but I can't think of a way to dynamically assign a different name for each ID **and** then grab it in the actions.php

Can anyone provide some guidance on how I can pass the SN field to my delete query in the separate file?

Thank you!

Comment: why did you comment out the part that executes the delete query?

Comment: you also shouldn't be wrapping all that php/mysql inside `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry that I've offended you with my lack of acceptance on previous questions and my delay in responding. To the first, that's 100% my bad and I'll go through previous questions and mark as answered (if applicable). As to the second, I submitted the question before I left work and I've just got home so...no, I'm not ignoring.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the delete section is commented out because I want to fix the ID issue first before I start deleting the last row of my test data every time I press delete. And I'll make the form tags more specific.

Comment: @user3074653 That's why I wrote *"Did you leave the question (gone feeding the kids?)"* - I see a lot of those happen where they have to leave which is perfectly fine, given that they respond to a person in particular that posted a comment. Otherwise, they probably won't keep that tab open until they return. We see a lot of questions that are left unresponsive or just don't bother. This wasn't the case with you and I'd like to thank you for that. Btw; you didn't offend me :-)

Comment: @user3074653 Try changing the `$id = $_POST["id"];` to a GET, since you're fetching those rows from the db and from the hidden input; I think that should make it work. check for errors on the query and do look at the HTML source to see what is in there (or not).

Comment: @Fred-ii- but will the GET resolve the issue I had that I am defining multiple hidden inputs with the same name?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the value of the inputs are different, but the name is the same (it is always 'id')

Comment: @user3074653 *"but will the GET resolve the issue..."* - It should. if you're unsure if something is going to break, make a copy of your db and work with that one until you get it right. That way if something doesn't go right, delete the test db and make up another from the original; that's what I do.  *"the value of the inputs are different"* - As it should be, since you're wanting to delete a specific row.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've managed to solve it by wrapping each table row in its own form. Then it works. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you, *cheers* and you're welcome.